# Does JUnit 3 have something analogous to @BeforeClass?

Tags: java, junit

I'm forced to use JUnit 3 for a particular test suite.  I understand `setUp()` and `tearDown()` serve the function of `@Before` and `@After`, but is there an analogue of `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` for things that should happen once before the tests start, and once after all tests are run?

Comment: @Basilevs sure, but this question googles well 

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, I should have searched SO better.

[Class teardown in junit 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646586/class-teardown-in-junit-3)

```
public static Test suite() {
  return new TestSetup(new TestSuite(YourTestClass.class)) {

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Global setUp ");
    }
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" Global tearDown ");
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score -5):

No, this is a new feature in JUnit4.